# Pre-populating a multi-dimensional form with DB data - PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am creating an e-commerce site using PHP. It is set up so that each product can have multiple attributes (size, colour, etc.) and these different options can have different prices. We are also selling in multiple countries and due to shipping costs there are also different prices for each country. I set up a form to gather this information like so:

```
$params = [$attribute];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id=?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$attributeCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($attributeCount > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $attribute_name = $row["name"];
    }
}
$price_form .= "<table class='table'>";
$price_form .= "<thead>";
$price_form .= "<td>$attribute_name</td>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
$countryCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($countryCount > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $country_name = $row["country"];
        $price_form .= "<td>$country_name</td>";
    }
}
$price_form .= "</thead>";
$params = [$attribute];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id=?";
$attributeResult = DB::run($sql,$params);
foreach ($attributeResult as $value) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
        $attributeColumn = "attribute".$i;
        $checkbox = "checkbox".$i;
        $priceValue = "priceValue".$i;
        $priceCurrency = "priceCurrency".$i;
        $priceAttribute = "priceAttribute".$i;
        if($value[$attributeColumn] != ""){
            $price_form .= "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='$checkbox' id='$checkbox' value='$checkbox'>$value[$attributeColumn]</td>";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
            $countryResult = DB::run($sql);
            while ($row = $countryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $country_id = $row["id"];
                $country_currency = $row["currency"];
                $price_form .= '<td>';
                $price_form .= '<input type="text" placeholder='.$country_currency.' name='.$priceValue.'_'.$country_id.' id='.$priceValue.'_'.$country_id.' size="10">';
                $price_form .= '<input type="hidden" value='.$country_id.' name='.$priceCurrency.'_'.$country_id.' id='.$priceCurrency.'_'.$country_id.'>';
                $price_form .= '<input type="hidden" value='.$i.' name='.$priceAttribute.'_'.$country_id.' id='.$priceAttribute.'_'.$country_id.'>';
                $price_form .= '</td>';
            }
        }
        $price_form .= '</tr>';
    }
}
$price_form .= "</table>";
```

So at present there are only two countries but each product can have up to 15 attributes so that gives us a form like this:

```html
<div id="price_form_div">
<table class="table"><thead><tr><td>Colour</td><td>Ireland</td><td>United Kingdom</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1">Black</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue1_1" id="priceValue1_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency1_1" id="priceCurrency1_1"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceAttribute1_1" id="priceAttribute1_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue1_2" id="priceValue1_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency1_2" id="priceCurrency1_2"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceAttribute1_2" id="priceAttribute1_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2">White</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue2_1" id="priceValue2_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency2_1" id="priceCurrency2_1"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceAttribute2_1" id="priceAttribute2_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue2_2" id="priceValue2_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency2_2" id="priceCurrency2_2"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceAttribute2_2" id="priceAttribute2_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="checkbox3">Purple</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue3_1" id="priceValue3_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency3_1" id="priceCurrency3_1"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="priceAttribute3_1" id="priceAttribute3_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue3_2" id="priceValue3_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency3_2" id="priceCurrency3_2"><input type="hidden" value="3" name="priceAttribute3_2" id="priceAttribute3_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" value="checkbox4">Yellow</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue4_1" id="priceValue4_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency4_1" id="priceCurrency4_1"><input type="hidden" value="4" name="priceAttribute4_1" id="priceAttribute4_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue4_2" id="priceValue4_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency4_2" id="priceCurrency4_2"><input type="hidden" value="4" name="priceAttribute4_2" id="priceAttribute4_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" value="checkbox5">Red</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue5_1" id="priceValue5_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency5_1" id="priceCurrency5_1"><input type="hidden" value="5" name="priceAttribute5_1" id="priceAttribute5_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue5_2" id="priceValue5_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency5_2" id="priceCurrency5_2"><input type="hidden" value="5" name="priceAttribute5_2" id="priceAttribute5_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" value="checkbox6">Orange</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue6_1" id="priceValue6_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency6_1" id="priceCurrency6_1"><input type="hidden" value="6" name="priceAttribute6_1" id="priceAttribute6_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue6_2" id="priceValue6_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency6_2" id="priceCurrency6_2"><input type="hidden" value="6" name="priceAttribute6_2" id="priceAttribute6_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" id="checkbox7" value="checkbox7">Blue</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue7_1" id="priceValue7_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency7_1" id="priceCurrency7_1"><input type="hidden" value="7" name="priceAttribute7_1" id="priceAttribute7_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue7_2" id="priceValue7_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency7_2" id="priceCurrency7_2"><input type="hidden" value="7" name="priceAttribute7_2" id="priceAttribute7_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" id="checkbox8" value="checkbox8">Green</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue8_1" id="priceValue8_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency8_1" id="priceCurrency8_1"><input type="hidden" value="8" name="priceAttribute8_1" id="priceAttribute8_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue8_2" id="priceValue8_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency8_2" id="priceCurrency8_2"><input type="hidden" value="8" name="priceAttribute8_2" id="priceAttribute8_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" id="checkbox9" value="checkbox9">Pink</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue9_1" id="priceValue9_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency9_1" id="priceCurrency9_1"><input type="hidden" value="9" name="priceAttribute9_1" id="priceAttribute9_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue9_2" id="priceValue9_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency9_2" id="priceCurrency9_2"><input type="hidden" value="9" name="priceAttribute9_2" id="priceAttribute9_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" id="checkbox10" value="checkbox10">Grey</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue10_1" id="priceValue10_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency10_1" id="priceCurrency10_1"><input type="hidden" value="10" name="priceAttribute10_1" id="priceAttribute10_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue10_2" id="priceValue10_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency10_2" id="priceCurrency10_2"><input type="hidden" value="10" name="priceAttribute10_2" id="priceAttribute10_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox11" id="checkbox11" value="checkbox11">Brown</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue11_1" id="priceValue11_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency11_1" id="priceCurrency11_1"><input type="hidden" value="11" name="priceAttribute11_1" id="priceAttribute11_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue11_2" id="priceValue11_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency11_2" id="priceCurrency11_2"><input type="hidden" value="11" name="priceAttribute11_2" id="priceAttribute11_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox12" id="checkbox12" value="checkbox12">Spearmint</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue12_1" id="priceValue12_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency12_1" id="priceCurrency12_1"><input type="hidden" value="12" name="priceAttribute12_1" id="priceAttribute12_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue12_2" id="priceValue12_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency12_2" id="priceCurrency12_2"><input type="hidden" value="12" name="priceAttribute12_2" id="priceAttribute12_2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox13" id="checkbox13" value="checkbox13">Lime Green</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="€" name="priceValue13_1" id="priceValue13_1" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="priceCurrency13_1" id="priceCurrency13_1"><input type="hidden" value="13" name="priceAttribute13_1" id="priceAttribute13_1"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="£" name="priceValue13_2" id="priceValue13_2" size="10"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="priceCurrency13_2" id="priceCurrency13_2"><input type="hidden" value="13" name="priceAttribute13_2" id="priceAttribute13_2"></td></tr></tbody></table><br></div>
```

Note that each cell has two hidden inputs for the country and attribute values. Also some products only use certain attributes (something might only come in 2 colours) therefore there is a checkbox beside each set so only the ones that are checked get uploaded to the database.

So I end up with a database structure like this, with 3 products (1, 2, 3) which all only have one attribute (1) but they are being sold in two countries (1, 2) and the prices for each:

```
id  product country attribute   value
6       3       1       1       562
5       3       2       1       443
4       2       1       1       416
3       2       2       1       318
2       1       1       1       196
1       1       2       1       142
```

My issue is when it comes to editing the products. I want to be able to rebuild this form with the data from this table already filled in. I would like the appropriate checkboxes to be selected and the value fields populated.

I've tried a few things. I've managed to get it to have the checkbox selected with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE product=?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$priceCount = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($priceCount > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $country = $row["country"];
        $price_attribute = $row["attribute"];
        $value = $row["value"];
    }
}
$price_form .= "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='$checkbox' id='$checkbox' value='$checkbox'";
if($attribute == $i){ $price_form .= " checked";}
$price_form .= ">$value[$attributeColumn]</td>";
```

What can I try next?